# PostgreSQL to MySQL conversion of large tables

Tags: mysql, linux, postgresql, ubuntu, database-migration

I need to convert a table from PostgreSQL to MySQL. The size of the table is **5.2GB**. I am doing it on workbench, but after some **3minutes** I am getting errors like below.

**HY001:14:Out of memory in allocating item buffer.**

I have tried changing **innodb_log_file_size, innodb_log_buffer_size, query_cache_size,  key_buffer_size** and some other variables, but no go.

Can someone help me in doing this. Is there is any other conversion tools to do this. It will be great if I solve the above error too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that workbench is running out of memory and not the database itself. I would try another tool like http://www.lightbox.ca/pg2mysql.php

Comment: For your information I tried this, and the process runs for 2minutes and gives me a error,
 **Out of memory (allocated -1202716672) (tried to allocate 1046 bytes) in /home/ubbvphp007/Downloads/pg2mysql-1.9/pg2mysql.inc.php on line 77**

Comment: I have allocated PHP memory_limit of **12800M**.